# How can i delete unnecessary contours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]
[image]

Hello, first picture there are protrusions on the figure. I don't want to get these contours. The result contour I want is in the second picture.I'm waiting for your help, thank you.

Comment: Save as .svg and edit in Illustrator/Affinity?

Answer (score 4):

This is a way to do it:

Fill the contour. Do a morphological Opening on the image to remove small foliage, and subtract the eroded image from the last image, to only keep its contour.

[image]

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("E:/1/1.jpg",0)
th, img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
[contours, hierarchy] = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img2 = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (255,255,255), -1)
# cv2.imwrite("E:/1/2.jpg",img2)

kernel = np.ones((21,21),np.uint8)
img2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# cv2.imwrite("E:/1/3.jpg",img2)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img2,kernel,iterations = 1)
img2 = img2 - erosion

# cv2.imwrite("E:/1/4.jpg",img2)
```

Comment: God bless you brother :)

Answer (score 0):

Try contour approximation. Adjust epsilon as necessary.

```
# epsilon is the maximum distance from contour to approximated contour. It is an accuracy parameter. 
# A wise selection of epsilon is needed to get the correct output.
epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)

approx_contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
```